# @CreationTimestamp in Hibernate is storing wrong date in database

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, creation-timestamp

I have used hibernate `@CreationTimestamp` (`import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;`) in my spring boot project for the field `private Date createdDate`;
and Date is of `import java.util.Date;` to store the default current timestamp. This date is not having any setter method in java code.

I am using PostgreSQL 9.5.4 version and when I save, the created date is saved as 28th October 2022 but the correct created date which should have been stored is 23rd January 2023. But `@UpdateTimestamp` is working correctly. The picture from the database depicts the same.

[image]

```
@Entity
@Audited
public class EntityClassName implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6004021640401026397L;
    ...
    private String createdBy;
    
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Date createdDate;
    
    private String updatedBy;
    
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Date updatedDate;

}
```

**Update 1:**
So when I use `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)` it stores the correct date in the database. Please find below code snippet:

```
@CreationTimestamp
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date createdDate;
```

But in the same database schema for other tables, I haven't used `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)` and it is still working fine and storing the correct date in the database.

Can someone please guide what is going wrong here? Appreciate your help

Comment: You are sure the records are newly created?

Comment: You shouldn't longer use `java.util.Date` you should switch to classes from the `java.time` API

Comment: Yes October and not December, sorry for typing wrong info. I will edit it now

Comment: Yes 100% sure, records are newly created. There were some other columns as well which had the same value I submitted to the database.

Comment: Sure, Jens, I will try with java.time and will let this group know if it is working